# Запуск проекта с Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Подскажите как запустить этот проект? https://github.com/CaymanJava/online_banking

У меня не выходит запустить его, остановился на ошибке, что описана [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952126/tomcat-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment1588473_952126)

Я собрал проект, после зашел на локалхост тома, Manager App и там загрузил проект, после чего нажал старт и выводит

> ОШИБКА - Application at context path [/online_banking] could not be
>   started

в вопросе, что я добавил выше. написано, что нужно добавить переменную DATABASE_URL, у меня не установлена была postgres, я установил, но ошибка сохранилась, нужно как то еще что то добавлять для этого, что мне еще нужно сделать?

Помогите с запуском, очень нужно запустить этот проект

Comment: Не надо создавать новых тем для одного и того же вопроса. По теме - Вы, после установки, задали эту переменную?

Comment: @Sergi Если она не создается автоматически, то я искал как установить ее вручную ибо обычно нужно путь специальный, но такой не нашел
Нужно просто в папку bin?

Comment: погуглите "как задать пременную среды в Windows", а значение - URL для вашей базы, что-то типа: `postgres://YourUserName:YourPassword@YourHost:5432/YourDatabase`